# Connecting to Postgresql from macOS (Catalina/BigSur)

Tags: postgresql

I ve been trying to establish a conn from -

1. ODBC manager
2. MS Excel (2016)
3. PgAdmin4
4. Postico
5. DBViz and
6. Oracle SQL Developer to Postgresql

*I have all the conn string parameters (trying to connect to a remote Postgresql server)

None of the above work BUT

*I wrote a python script and could connect with ease. I could also connect via psql."

*Installed psqlodbc, unixodbc on my mac, root, key and client certs are in place (~/.postgresql)

The errors I get are -

1. GSSAPI auth is not supported (pgadmin4 and postico)
2. Fatal: Connection needs a valid client certificate (with DBViz and SQL Developer)

I also tried with the jdbc drivers (for accessing MS SQL Server) and that works fine (via DBViz/excel/sql developer) but not (Postgresql DB)

Any help? Thank you!

Comment: What auth method are you wanting to use?

Comment: @jjanes - I use Kerberos auth

Comment: What is the exact copy and paste of the error message?  I think think this means those clients were not compiled to support kerberos.

Comment: @jjanes - The exact copy is here below:
FATAL: Connection needs a valid client certificate. 
Also, just to let you know, this is a workaround, the ideal solution is we are wanting to connect Tableau and Postgresql.

Comment: But what about the exact copy of the 1st error message?

Comment: The 2nd error message indicates they are trying to connect with a client SSL cert, but can't find it.  The location of ~/.postgresql is used by libpq-based programs, like `psql` and simple python scripts.  But those other tools are not libpq-based and probably require their own way of placing the cert and key files.  Check their docs.

Comment: will do @jjanes. Thank you!

Comment: FATAL: connection requires a valid client certificate
Invalid username or password (trying to connect to Postgresql from Tableau)

Comment: @jjanes error occurred while communicating with PostgreSQL
Invalid username or password.
Error Code: 1CB20D9A
FATAL: connection requires a valid client certificate
Invalid username or password.

Comment: @jjanes, all my issues are now resolved! It was a db config issue. Thank you so much!